# control flow of callbacks with db returns in node js

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am newbie in node js and facing a problem with control flow of callbacks with db returns.

What I want is the following sequence:

```
console.log('>>>>>>>  first log in F1   >>>>>>');
console.log('>>>>>>>  second log in F1   >>>>>>');
console.log('>>>>>>>  first log in F2   >>>>>>');
console.log('>>>>>>>  second log in F2   >>>>>>');
console.log('>>>>>>>  first log in F3   >>>>>>');
console.log('>>>>>>>  second log in F3   >>>>>>');
console.log('>>>>>>>  first log in F4   >>>>>>');
console.log('>>>>>>>  second log in F4   >>>>>>');
console.log('>>>>>>>  third log in F4   >>>>>>');
console.log('finished ');
```

But I am not gettting in that order. Code looks like as follows:

```
F1(req).then(function(result){
    return F2(result);
    }).then(function(result){
        return F3(result);
    }).then(function(result){
        return F4(result);
    }).then(function(result){
        console.log('finished ');
    })

var F1 = function(req) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        console.log('>>>>>>>  first log in F1   >>>>>>');
        var result = {};
        result.emailId = req.body.emailId;
        common.db.collection('document1').findOne({email: req.body.emailId}, function (error, document1object) {
            console.log('>>>>>>>  second log in F1   >>>>>>');
        }); 
        resolve(result);
    });
};
var F2 = function(result) {
    console.log('>>>>>>>  first log in F2   >>>>>>');
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        common.db.collection('document2').findOne({email: result.emailId}, function (err, document2object) {
                console.log('>>>>>>>  second log in F2   >>>>>>');
                result.value1 = document2object._id;
        }); 
        resolve(result);
    });
};
var F3 = function(result) {
    console.log('>>>>>>>  first log in F3   >>>>>>');
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        common.db.collection('document3').insertOne({email: result.emailId}, function (errr, document3object) {
            console.log('>>>>>>>  second log in F3   >>>>>>');
            result.value2 = document3object.insertedId;
        });
        resolve( result);
    });
};
var F4 = function(result) {
    console.log('>>>>>>>  first log in F4   >>>>>>');
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        client.post("urlPart1"+result.value2+"urlPart2", 
        args, function (data, response) {
           console.log('>>>>>>>  second log in F4   >>>>>>');
        });
        console.log('>>>>>>>  third log in F4   >>>>>>');
        resolve( result);
    });
};
```

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because... async.

Your request get all evaluated at the same time, thus you're not getting the log in the order you want. If you want a specific order, you'll have to start the next request when the last one is done, i.e. in the callback function of the previous one.

Comment: Thanks Nicovank :)